# How can I update the version of SQLite in my Flask/SQLAlchemy App?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I wish to use the latest version of SQLite3 (3.30.1) because of its new capability to handle SQL 'ORDER BY ... ASC NULLS LAST' syntax as generated by the SQLAlchemy nullslast() function.

My application folder env\Scripts contains the existing (old) version of sqlite3.dll (3.24), however when I replace it, there is no effect. In fact, if I rename that DLL, the application still works fine with DB accesses.

So, how do I update the SQLite version for an application?

My environment:
Windows 10, 64-bit (I downloaded a 64-bit SQlite3 DLL version). I am running with pyCharm, using a virtual env.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that the applicable sqlite3.dll is determined first by a Windows OS defined lookup. It first goes through the PATH variable, finding and choosing the first version it finds in any of those paths.

In this case, probably true for all pyCharm/VirtualEnv setups, a version found in my user AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs folder was selected.

When I moved that out of the way, it was able to find the version in my env\Scripts folder, so that the upgraded DLL was used, and the sQLAlchemy nullslast() function did its work.